Custom userId claim on idtoken issued by Identity provder (Auth0)
My question is whether it’s possible to add a user ID generated from my own database as a custom user ID claim in the ID token, which is signed and issued by an external identity provider. Specifically, I am using Auth0 as the external identity provider.
I have a frontend and a backend in .NET, where the frontend initiates an OpenID Connect flow by hitting my backend, which then redirects to Auth0 for authentication. Once the user logs in or registers, Auth0 issues the ID token, and the user is redirected back to my backend. Upon inspecting the ID token, I see a user ID claim generated by Auth0, but I need to add my own custom user ID generated from my backend's database as an additional claim in the ID token.
In .NET, I’ve tried hooking into various events such as OnTokenValidated, but at that point, the token has already been signed and issued, so modifying it is not an option.
I’ve also read Auth0’s documentation, which suggests using Actions to add custom claims. However, since the claim I need is unique to each user and generated by my application, I would have to expose my local machine to the internet to allow Auth0 Actions to retrieve this user ID. I want to avoid exposing my backend while developing locally.
I’m looking for any advice on how to add this custom user ID claim to the ID token issued by an external identity provider, or if it’s even possible. I’ve mentioned Auth0, but I am open to solutions with other external identity providers if someone has solved a similar issue.
Additionally, I noticed that in .NET, there is an OpenIdConnect event called RedirectToIdentityProvider, which I can override. In this event, I considered generating a custom user ID and passing it as a parameter when the user is redirected to Auth0. Then, I could potentially read this parameter from Auth0 Actions. However, this approach doesn’t make sense either, since it would result in generating a new user ID every time the user logs in or registers. This user ID should only be generated once, during the registration process, which is something handled by Auth0.


add a user ID generated from my own database as a custom user ID claim
in the ID token.....the claim I need is unique to each user and
generated by my application

According to the description, the flow shall be
1.hit your app

redirect to external auth provider to finish the OIDC authentication

redirect back to your app along with the id token for the current user.


Then since the custom claim should contain unique user information which stored in your database, so that even if we have a solution to add this claim into id token generated by OAuth0, we have to know who is current the user ahead, we could query the database to get the custom claim value next. In this scenario, we need extra steps

know who the current user is and obtain required claim value from database

go back to external identity provider to regenerate a new id token contained the custom claim.


If so, even if there's such a method existed, I'm afraid this is not a good option. I think storing the custom claim value in memory DB like Redis will be a better option. Or we might put the claim in access token, because Id token is used for authentication while access token is for authorization which can represent user too.

Thank you for your recommendation, but I need the flexibility to add some unique custom claims to my tokens, so I don't rely on Redis.

Thank you for your kind reply, then I'm afraid access token shall be a better option. By the way, if it's an MVC app we can use session to store user information as well. Id token is designed for return back user sign in information, and access token is used for accessing resources in subsequent stages. That's why I say we might add the custom claim into access token.

I thank you for your helpful suggestions and recommendations. I really appreciate this. Do you have any ideas or thoughts on some flows or how I can solve my problem if I add a custom user ID claim to the access token? After reading more about best practices, I believe you are right, and it probably belongs more appropriately in the access token. My application is just a .Net web api

I really appreciate your kind words and to be honest, I'm also thinking about your issue when I investigate another question today. For access token, it can be generated by external indentity provider, then whether we could add custom claims into access token depends on the provider itselves. I usually work on Azure AD but it doesn't meet your requirement, maybe there's a provider implementing OAuth protocal could help you but I don't know that. But anyway we could create our own jwt authorization so that generating access token based on our custom business.

If you think custom Jwt auth is flexible and can be maintained by yourself completely but just not familar with it, you an take a look at this sample code.

I am using Auth0, and they mention that you can use their Actions to add custom claims to tokens. These Action functions are triggered when the user is logged in, but the tokens have not yet been signed and issued. I could call an endpoint in my backend here, but I'm unsure if I will then need to expose my local development environment to the internet. https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/create-custom-claims

In relation to your other suggestion, will it require that I move away from an external identity provider

no, external ideneity provider helps your app to integrate authentication, and some of them also provides authorization feature. What I shared just provide with you an extra authorization scheme.
